# Can the opening questions on this site be connected to an opening tree search?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

How about connecting every chess position question to a chess (move based) tree?

Also, to introduce a tree based search to navigate the questions?

The chess opening (and chess games as a whole) has a tree structure and is best navigated as a tree. To get 10 or more questions per day, they have to concern concrete chess positions. To improve the navigation and overview of such questions and answers, such a tree navigation would be great to have. Over time, it would be cool to try to cover as much "chess space" as possible here on this site.

Comment: Ultimately then, we could have a search interface where users just play out moves on a board, and see a list of relevant questions get populated as they do. That would be really sweet; this is a cool idea.

Comment: +1 I love this idea.  I fear it may be difficult to implement though.  How will we go about capturing all of the chess positions listed?  I think the most effective method would be to write a script of some sort that scrapes the question (and each answer) as it is submitted to capture all of the different positions that occur.  Alternatively, you could have the user key in the position they feel best represents their question, but this would neglect all of the other positions in the game which may be of interest to others.

Answer (score 6):

Another search idea I had, which might be useful in itself and nicely complement the OP's suggestion, would have users be able to search such questions about concrete positions by employing (some kind of user-friendly wrapper of some subset of) the Chess Query Language, e.g. to search across the FEN and PGN contained in site questions for endings with certain material configurations, or any other queries that the CQL allows one to express. Between these two additional searching options, users would have great searching power across all phases of the game.

Comment: +1 I love you idea for a board as the search interface.  There are so many possibilities with this idea.